# Background on the Stone-von Neumann theorem

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, representation-theory, commutator

I'm actually a mathematician.
I'm required to give a lecture on the [Stone-von Neumann theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93von_Neumann_theorem). I already have all the **mathematical** details figured out, but I wish to make the lecture more interesting by giving the physical connection to the theorem.

Problem is, I don't recall much of the quantum physics course I took as an electrical engineering student 10 years ago.
Can you please give me a fair background on the theorem, in simple words, I can present as an intro to the mathematical details (Historical anecdotes, the relation to the wave function etc.)?

Comment: You should post this to [HSM.SE](https://hsm.stackexchange.com) instead. In the late 20s (through the late 40s!) there was confusion about all formulations/pictures of QM being absolutely equivalent, as they proved to be, and whether one could devise alternate formulations on first principles. That theorem set them all calming down.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't familiar with HSM.SE. I'll post there.

Comment: The question seems to be about why do unitary groups of operators $t\mapsto U(t)$ arise in QM? You could start by looking up Wigner's Thm https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner%27s_theorem